# String match in r

Tags: r, text, character, string-matching, mining

I have two data frames D1 and D2 as mentioned below
I want to compare D1 and D2 like "Issues" of `D1` with "list_of_issues" of `D2`

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Issues = c('CI', 'E,CI', 'H,A', 'CI,E')
Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
D1 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location, Customer)

Root_Cause = c('R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4')
List_of_Issues = c('A', 'A,H', 'E,CI', 'CI')  
D2 = data.frame(Root_Cause, List_of_Issues)
```

if issues are matching with the root cause then obtain the `Root_cause` in `D3` by generating a column `Root_Cause` like this in `D3`

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Issues = c('CI', 'E,CI', 'H,A', 'CI,E')
Location = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
Customer = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
Root_Cause = c('R4', 'R3', 'R2', 'R3')
D3 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location, Customer, Root_Cause)
```

Comment: so `D3` is your desirable result?

Comment: Yes D3 is my desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-fix using `data.table` and `setkey` (from `data.table`).

```
library(data.table) 
D1 <- as.data.table(D1)
setkey(D1, 'Issues') 

D2 <- as.data.table(D2) 
setkey(D2, 'List_of_Issues)

> D1
   ID Issues Location Customer
1:  1     CI        x        a
2:  4   CI,E        w        d
3:  2   E,CI        y        b
4:  3    H,A        z        c
> D2
   Root_Cause List_of_Issues
1:         R1              A
2:         R2            A,H
3:         R4           CI,E
4:         R3           E,CI

# Using the key to get the desired output
> D2[D1, ]
   Root_Cause List_of_Issues ID Location Customer
1:       <NA>             CI  1        x        a
2:         R4           CI,E  4        w        d
3:         R3           E,CI  2        y        b
4:       <NA>            H,A  3        z        c
```

Setting a `key` allows the `data.table` to be quickly sorted on that column. Since `data.table` works by reference, this makes the whole process really fast. The last line of code matches the entries of the `key` of `D1` with the `key` of `D2` and returns the `Root_Cause` for matching `key` entries in both `tables`.

It can be sorted by `ID` to get the desired output:

```
> D2[D1, ][order(ID)]
   Root_Cause List_of_Issues ID Location Customer
1:       <NA>             CI  1        x        a
2:         R3           E,CI  2        y        b
3:       <NA>            H,A  3        z        c
4:         R4           CI,E  4        w        d
```

In your example, the `Root_Cause` column of `D3` is `c(NA, 'R3', 'R2', 'R3')` which is incorrect - by default `A,H` is not the same as `H,A` which is why `R2` would not be matched. Secondly, `CI,E` matches `R4` in `D2` from your sample data.

You can always drop columns by setting them to `NULL` e.g. `Customer := NULL` and reorder columns by using `setcolorder()`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have edited my question a little bit. My desired output should be like if "Issues" column contains either  'CI,E' or 'E,CI' my root cause should be R3.